# Java - Passing and executing a function

Tags: java

Is there a way of passing a function to another function and then executing it?

```
functionCaller(functionToBeCalled());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java 8 you can use a method reference or lambda

```
functionCaller(this::functionToBeCalled);
```

or

```
functionCaller(() -> functionToBeCalled());
```

Comment: Thank you, finally a simple way.  I'll mark this as answer when I'll be able.

Comment: Note that `this::functionToBeCalled` won't work if you're in a static context.

Comment: @Tunaki in that case you need to know the class e.g. `MyClass::functionToBeCalled`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand very well your question, but effectively you can call a function in param of another function.

You can do this (I suppose your current language is Java):

```
// if write(...) and getValue() are static method of Writer class  
Writer.write(getValue());

// if write(...) and getValue() can just be used by instanciate an object
Writer writer = new Writer();
String val = writer.getValue();
writer.write(val);
```

There are basic Java programming lesson.
Thanks

Comment: The pattern the OP is looking for is the ability to pass in a function to be called, but is not called first.